# Add geometry information to a query

Tags: postgis

This query

```
SELECT 
     a.id,
     b.id AS id2,
     ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom)
 FROM riverscale.points a CROSS JOIN riverscale.points b
WHERE a.id != b.id;
```

generates this:

[image]

I am guessing the necessary information for creating a geomtery is in the column "st_makeline".

How can I convert this table into an object with a LINESTRING (or other) geometry that I can load in e.g. QGIS?

#

EDIT: 
When I try to create a table with this query I get this and I can't load it in QGIS.

```
CREATE TABLE riverscale.test as
   SELECT 
     a.id,
     b.id AS id2,
     ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom)
 FROM riverscale.points a CROSS JOIN riverscale.points b
WHERE a.id != b.id;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is indeed an issue with the line creation at the bottom of this; as it stands, that query will create *(invalid) same-point linestrings* when `a.geom` and `b.geom` happen to be the same row in your cross join. a query resulting in a column having more than one geometry type (including none, invalid and the above result) will have the generic `GEOMETRY` type, and QGIS resolves that ambiguity by showing the same layer for every geometric dimensionality (point to polygon). the answers here then simply enforce line geometries, but the actual issue is their falsey creation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I actually copied the wrong query to my question. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE riverscale.test AS
    SELECT 
         a.id,
         b.id AS id2,
         ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom)::geometry('LINESTRING', 3763) AS geom
     FROM riverscale.points a CROSS JOIN riverscale.points b
    WHERE a.id != b.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

It **is** a geometry already.

What you have is not a table but the result of a query. You have at least 2 options:

1) create a new table with the output and load it in QGIS

```
CREATE TABLE test as
  SELECT 
    a.id, 
    b.id AS id2,
    ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) as geom
  FROM riverscale.points a, riverscale.points b
```

2) load the tables in QGIS and query them. You can use the DBManager or a virtual layer

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can't load the table. I edited my question.

Comment: Make sure you add it to the geometry columns view

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The select query is not correct to generate the rows.

Rewrite the select statement defining which ids of riverscale.points is start and end of Make Line function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    b.id AS id2,
    ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) as geom
  FROM riverscale.points a, riverscale.points b
where a.id =1 and b.id=2
```

This will make the line between points with id’s 1 and 2